# How to pass publisher to callback

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to pass publisher to callback, as far as I can see this should work but keep getting errors: The two param case works without the publisher being passed.

```
 ImageGrabber igb(&SLAM);
ros::NodeHandle nh; 
ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>("/camera/depth-converted/image_raw", 1);
 
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> rgb_sub(nh, "/camera/rgb/image_raw", 100);
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> depth_sub(nh, "camera/depth_registered/image_raw", 100);
typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::Image> sync_pol;
message_filters::Synchronizer<sync_pol> sync(sync_pol(10), rgb_sub, depth_sub, &pub);
sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&ImageGrabber::GrabRGBD, &igb, _1, _3));
```

call back def:

```
void ImageGrabber::GrabRGBD(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msgRGB,const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msgD, const ros::Publisher *pub)
```

error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘message_filters::Synchronizer<message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > > >::Synchronizer(sync_pol, message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&, message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const ros::Publisher*)’
     message_filters::Synchronizer<sync_pol> sync(sync_pol(10), rgb_sub, depth_sub, &pub);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273714/how-to-pass-publisher-to-callback/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-10-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're trying to create a topic synchronizer with a publisher as an input, and the compiler is telling you that isn't allowed. You're only allowed to pass a policy and some number of subscribers to the `sync()` method.

Instead, you can either make your publisher a global variable, a class variable if your callback is a member of a class, or pass the publisher to the callback as one of the arguments when you use boost::bind.

Try:

```
sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&ImageGrabber::GrabRGBD, &igb, _1, _2, &pub));
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2017-10-21**:
did not work....but I did go ahead and make it a class var. Should I close this? It seem that it is just not permitted.